# using drools with jboss plugin for eclipse

Tags: jboss, eclipse-plugin, drools

I have eclipse kepler sr2.
Installed the jboss plugin http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/kepler/4.1.2.Final.html

I don't have any drools wizards available. Does anyone know why?

I expect to see any of the drools wizards as in the following image:

[image: drools wizards]
<sub>(source: [mastertheboss.com](http://www.mastertheboss.com/images/stories/wizarddrools.png))</sub>

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? You really need to explain the problem you have and what you have done to attempt to resolve it already. In its current form, this question is likely to be flagged for deletion.

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use the Eclipse Marketplace, or did you try to do it some other way? If you create a file in your project called `something.drl`, does it appear in the navigator with a DRL file icon?

Comment: I've used the market place.
The file appears with a plain file icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this plugin as an alternative:

http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/